# laravel, laravel-websockets, vue app deployment

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, laravel-websockets

the problem is that i have both the laravel app and vue app deployed under https://preprod.exemple.fr the vua app is deployed under https://preprod.exemple.fr and the laravel project is deployed under https://preprod.exemple.fr/api folder every things works fine for fetching apis but its not working for websockets the websockets is started but cant istablish connection from vue app and socket server to notice im using laravel-websockets package and im using laravel-echo and pusher.js in vue app i think tehre is a conflict between the laravel app path and the domain is there  a way to fix that or do you suggest any other solution

i have tried to what is mentioned up